# SDL2 fails to get display mode inside virtual machine (No available video device)

Tags: c, virtual-machine, virtualbox, sdl-2

Basically, SDL fails to acquire display mode when running inside a VirtualBox machine.

*SDL_GetNumDisplayModes()* fails reporting -1 then *SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)* fails with *No available video device*.

```
int main(void)
{
    int numberOfDrivers = SDL_GetNumVideoDrivers();
    printf("Number of drivers: %d\n", numberOfDrivers);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDrivers; i++)
        printf("Driver name: %s\n", SDL_GetVideoDriver(i));

    int numberOfDisplays = SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays();
    printf("Number of displays: %d\n", numberOfDisplays);

    printf("Display 0 mode: %d\n", SDL_GetNumDisplayModes(0));

    if (SDL_InitSubSystem(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
        SDL_Log("SDL fails to initialize video subsystem!\n%s", SDL_GetError());

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
Number of drivers: 2
Driver name: x11
Driver name: dummy
Number of displays: 0
Display 0 mode: -1
INFO: SDL fails to initialize video subsystem!
No available video device
Unable to initialize system
```

VirtualBox machine running Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit guest inside Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit host. Application is 32 bit.

Is there a way to resolve?

Comment: Are you running x11 on guest system? Can you run any other x11 program? If you're trying to do something very specific, you should describe it in the question.

Comment: The code that I reported isn't a very specific application

Comment: Yes, but something like "required to use framebuffer device instead of x11" is. Even passing hardware accelerated GL to VM is something that could be considered unusual. As it stands now, I have no idea what your environment and goals are.

Comment: I want to use a virtual machine for developing SDL application. But if I can't run/debug the application it is unuseful. I don't have a specific request, I want to see video/audio output of my application, if I can use another way it's ok, x11 is not a request

Comment: `$ loginctl show-session c2 -p Type` --> `Type=x11`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

There was 2 problems, one in the example code.

1. The first one was that *SDL_GetNumDisplayModes()* must be call after
   that video system has been initialized
2. The second one, **No available video device**, a problem that is
   very widespread on stackoverflow and on the web, was that
   **libgl1-mesa-glx** was missing

So, for **No available video device** error you need **xorg-dev libx11-dev libgl1-mesa-glx** libraries, maybe xorg-dev installs libx11-dev